# Flash CS5 iOs documentation

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3

Helo folks. I am really excited about the development for iOs devices on the brand new Adobe Flash CS5. I tried searching a documentation for this, but I cannot found. How can I view the possibilities and documentations for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, CS5's been out for a LOOONG time already. :P

Here's a simple tutorial:
http://www.lynda.com/Flash-CS5-tutorials/Flash-Professional-CS5-Creating-a-Simple-Game-for-iOS-Devices/77863-2.html

I don't think there is any official Flash documentation for iOS, but I can't get to my Windows partition right now, so I can't check. If there is, it should be in the Help (F1).
But here's some official adobe content to get you started:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

Answer (score 0):

Adobe is actually consistently pumping out new documentation, tutorials, and examples of Adobe AIR for iOS, Android, and BlackBerry Playbook development.

Also, I think what he meant was Flash CS5.5, not CS5.

Here are some links that might help:

- [Developing for iOS using Flash Professional](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html)
- [Build iOS Applications using Flex and Flash Builder 4.5](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/build-ios-applications-using-flex-and-flash-builder-45/) (Video)
- [Mobile development using Adobe Flex 4.5 SDK and Flash Builder 4.5](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile-development-flex-flashbuilder.html)

Ultimately, you're developing with Adobe AIR and targeting specific, newly-available-for-targetting platforms and devices. There are many things to consider (screen sizes, device orientations, sensors, platforms, and more) and the links above should give you a starting point. The [Adobe AIR Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html) has the above links and many more to help you on your way.